# Error running timer: (void-variable message) in Emacs init.el

Tags: variables, compiler-errors, emacs, elisp, lexical-closures

Why do I get `Error running timer: (void-variable message)`
in the function below in my `init.el - Emacs?

```lisp
(defun cypher/cowsayx-sclock (in-minutes message)
  (interactive "nSet the time from now - min.: \nsWhat: ")
  (run-at-time (* in-minutes 60)
               nil
               (lambda ()
                 (message "%S" message)
                 (shell-command (format "xcowsay %s" (shell-quote-argument
                                                      message))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn on `lexical-binding`, for that `message` occurrence in the lambda not to be treated as a free variable. It's a lexical variable local to function `cypher/cowsayx-sclock`, but within the lambda it's free.

Otherwise, you need to instead substitute the *value* of variable `message` in the lambda expression, and use that as a list. Here's a backquoted expression that gives you that list with the `message` value substituted.

```lisp
`(lambda ()
   (message "%S" ',message)
   (shell-command (format "xcowsay %s" (shell-quote-argument ',message)))
```

But this is less performant than using `lexical-binding`, which produces a closure for the lambda, encapsulating the value of `message`.

See the Elisp manual, node [Using Lexical Binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html).

You can, for example, just put this at the end of a comment line as the first line of your file:

```lisp
  -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```

For example, if your code is in file `foo.el` then this could be its first line:

```lisp
;;; foo.el --- Code that does foo things.   -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
```

Comment: Worked beautifully...
I still need to study the proper way you suggested here: "You need to turn on lexical-binding, for that message occurrence in the lambda not to be treated as a free variable..."

Comment: I've added an example of setting `lexical-binding` to `t` for the scope of a given file. That's the easiest way to take care of this, typically.

Comment: If the answer is acceptable you can "accept" it. You can of course instead wait for a better answer. ;-)

Comment: Where is the accept button? I cannot see it. The answer is really great! Worked beautifully, as I said before...

Comment: You can click on the big gray check button to the left of the answer.

Comment: Ok. But it is still confusing for people to start using stackoverflow. The devs should make thinks more friendly to normal users... There should be a legend or clear explanation or a video showing how to use all these buttons...